# How to pass selected row string in table view to another ViewController page? (Swift 2)

Tags: ios, storyboard, swift2

I am running Xcode 7.3 and using Swift 2.2. I am having trouble passing data from my first view controller to the second view controller. I've created a variable `string` in my first view controller that holds the selected row in the tableview and it works. I have also created another variable `string` in my second view controller that should hold the name of the selected row, then pass the text to a label.

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import ParseUI

class FruitListPage: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


var selectedFruit = String()

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let fruitName:Scanner2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("scanPage") as! Scanner2
    fruitName.loadView()
    let nameShop = textArray[indexPath.row]
    print(nameShop)
    selectedFruit = nameShop

    print(selectedFruit)

    fruitName.selectedFruit2 = selectedFruit

}
```

Everything works completely fine unit here in the first view controller and I can see the fruit name every time I press a row in the tableview. The real problem is that `selectedFruit2` string in the second view controller never grabs the data from the first view controller. Any clue?

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class Scanner2: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var fruitNameLabel: UILabel!

var selectedFruit2 = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print(selectedFruit2)

}

}
```

Comment: `loadView` documentation: "You should never call this method directly". Also note that you are setting `selectedFruit2` _after_ you have loaded the view. Removing the `loadView` will probably fix your problem although `viewWillAppear(_:)` will be probably safer than `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect your viewController in storyBoard with a segue and set its identifier as "scanPageSegue" for instance... then:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("scanPageSegue", sender: textArray[indexPath.row])
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "scanPageSegue" {
        if let fruitName = segue.destinationViewController as? Scanner2, 
           selectedFruit = sender as? String {
            fruitName.selectedFruit2 = selectedFruit
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it was very helpful and easy... I tried the prepareforsegue function before but the real important part for me was to connect storyboard with segue and to do performseguewithidentifier, then do prepareforsegue.
I was stuck on this for nearly 3 days now. Is this something new in swift 2?

Comment: Not really, this is the basilar mechanism to use in storyBoard, it was the same also before swift :D Anyway... now you know it. Basically you never need to instantiate programmatically a VC with storyboard, use segue instead, you can also use a custom subclass for segue with your custom transitions.

Answer (score 1):

You could try making a global variable and in the `override func prepareForSegue` method, initialize it with `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!.row`. This is how I did it and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, in your tableView:didSelectedRowAtIndexPath:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let fruitName:Scanner2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("scanPage") as! Scanner2
    selectedFruit = textArray[indexPath.row]
    fruitName.selectedFruit2 = selectedFruit
    self.presentViewController(fruitName,animated:true,completion:nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
let destinationVC = segue.destinationController
destinationVC.string = textArray[indexPath] //this is the string in second view controller
}
}
```